# SnowSQL JSONL vs JSON

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to load JSONL using the the JSON `file format type='JSON'`?  Or would I need to convert the JSONL to JSON?

As it stands right now I am able to stage the data but when I try to copy into a table the query errors out stating there is a data error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSV format to read each line of JSONL (with a non-common delimiter), then parse them using PARSE_JSON.

Sample test.jsonl:

```
{ "id":1, "name":"Gokhan"}
{ "id":2, "name":"Jack"}
{ "id":3, "name":"Joe"}
```

Sample file format object:

```
create file format jsonl type=CSV field_delimiter = '*xyz*';
```

Reading using parse_json:

```
select parse_json($1) js, js:id, js:name from @my_stage (file_format=>jsonl);
```

Comment: for some reason I still had to use file format json because there were special characters in the json doc that was triggering errors.  For exaple `//` was found in the doc and it was hanging up the table insert process.